# Can I install a "retrofit" hot water recirc pump with a dedicated return?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, pump

I'm looking to install a hot water recirculation pump in a *new construction* bathroom addition with all the *walls currently open* to the crawl space.<sup>(1)</sup> In doing so, I plan to add a "tepid" water return line instead of using the "cold water supply" returns that all the retrofit recirc pumps come with.<sup>(2)</sup>

Many of the retrofit kits I've looked at come with a 4-way connector valve like this:

[image]
<sup>Image from [HomeDepot.com](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Watts-Hot-Water-Recirculating-System-with-Built-In-Timer-0955800/100426993#overlay) with my annotations</sup>

My thought is to modify the installation to have the "Cold Supply In" connected to the "tepid return" and cap off the "Cold Supply to Faucet", like this:

[image]

As I see it, this would push the water down the "tepid water return" instead of the "cold supply", using the dedicated return line, leaving the cold supply side cold. The cold supply would be attached directly to the cold water tap, of course, as though there was no recirc pump installed.

**Will this work as I expect it to, or will this (potentially) cause some sort of issue that I'm not seeing?** Of course, there is more potential for leaky screw on connections as there will be a couple of extra, but those are easy to sort out when the water is first turned on.

---

Note: I know that my shopping effort is, so far, incomplete. I haven't yet asked around at some of the local plumbing supply places, so I'm certain there are options that I haven't yet discovered. As of now, however, the majority of the pumps I've seen at the big-box stores seem to be retro-fit models and not new construction, therefore, they have some sort of crossover like this.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>The wiring is not yet complete either, so I can install an outlet for the recirc pump anywhere I need to. It will, of course, be GFCI protected.

<sup>(2)</sup>My intention in doing it this way is that it just seems to make more sense, as pushing some warmer water into the cold water supply side seems counter productive since I'll have to wait for that to flush out of the cold water line if I just want cold water.

Comment: Am i missing something on how those cold water returns works?  If I understand, you will have 40 pounds coming in on the hot side and 40 pounds coming in on the cold side, basically a lock/block.  Your idea should work well, if you cannot find just a three tap.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Domestic Hot Water Recirculation Systems Design Considerations – Self Balancing Valves and Problems with Flow Devices](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5452a33de4b04219d5dae8f8/t/5cc1b7ef7817f79b088783cc/1556199413859/NY2676-Ruggierio-Presentation.pdf). There are lots of considerations, e.g. single floor or multiple floors, locating the valve(s) at the point(s) farthest from the water heater, ... .

Comment: I'm with you on that, @crip659, but, the tepid water _has_ to get pushed back against city water pressure at some point, so I presume the pumps are designed for that. I do know that our town is at a nominal 55PSI, so I have to overcome that.

Comment: Thanks, @HABO, I'm looking through that.

Comment: @FreeMan  Have two pumps on a outdoor wood furnace.  One is on the tank for the furnace(low pressure).  The other is on the hot water tank, so both just recirculating tank pressure in a loop(your tepid return line).  Imagine it must work somehow, just don't know.

Comment: @FreeMan The whole system is at 55PSI - the circulating pump does not have to "push back" against it, it merely needs to be adequately built that the casing doesn't break at that pressure, and apply a few feet of dynamic head (probably 1-5 PSI, if that much) to create circulation flow *around* the pressurized loop.

Comment: Ah, yeah, @Ecnerwal, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’ve got it exactly right and there are no downsides to your method that I am aware of.

Just so you are aware, that model of crossover valve that you show has both openings on the cold water side freely communicating with each other, so use whichever cold water opening works best for the tepid return with your particular layout.

I agree that it’s much better to have a dedicated tepid return line so you don’t have to wait for mains-cold water. That was not feasible at my house. One rarely mentioned benefit of using the cold water line as the return is that an adjacent toilet tank refills with tepid water if you flush before you use the sink. This helps to prevent condensation on the tank in humid weather.

These valves don’t last forever. I get about five years out of mine running on softened well water. When mine have failed, they failed “open”. The only way I knew was that it was taking forever to get cold water from the cold side because warm water was circulating back to the water heater continuously instead intermittently under thermostatic valve control. I revived one valve by soaking in white vinegar for a week. Another valve never recovered its thermostatic action even after a month in the vinegar. Now I occasionally check how long it takes to get cold water to verify that the valve is functioning properly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on maintenance! I'll definitely keep that in mind. My _preference_ is to find one with a temp sensor on the _outside_ of the pipe that's actually designed for new work installation, but I haven't found one (for a reasonable price) _yet_.

Comment: @FreeMan Alternative approach: Skip the thermostatic crossover valve entirely. Tee off the hot water supply to both the faucet and the tepid return. Install pump with internal flow check in the tepid return, arrow to water heater. Control the pump with a digital temp controller such as the one home brewers use. Put the temp sensor in contact with pipe at the T, wrap with insulation, set controller for 90F turning ON on falling temp. You get the same result as a crossover valve without the maintenance issues, plus the pump only runs when needed, not 24x7.